# PySpark: Remove leading numbers and full stop from dataframe column

Tags: pyspark

I'm trying to remove numbers and full stops that lead the names of horses in a betting dataframe.

The format is like this:

14. Horse Name
15. Horse Name

I would like the resulting df column to just have the horses name.

I've tried splitting the column at the full stop but am not getting the required result.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

runners_returns = runners_returns.withColumn('runner_name', F.split(F.col('runner_name'), '.'))
```

Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a Dataframe like the following.

```
df.show()
+---+-----------+
| ID|runner_name|
+---+-----------+
|  1|   123.John|
|  2|   5.42Anna|
|  3|   .203Josh|
|  4|    102Paul|
+---+-----------+
```

You can do remove the leading numbers and periods like this.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df = (df.withColumn("runner_name", 
         F.regexp_replace('runner_name', r'(^[\d\.]+)', '')))

df.show()
+---+-----------+
| ID|runner_name|
+---+-----------+
|  1|       John|
|  2|       Anna|
|  3|       Josh|
|  4|       Paul|
+---+-----------+
```

Comment: Excellent, thanks a million! I really need to get the hang of regular expressions.